Expectation and variance of SDE with arbitrary drift and GBM-style diffusion
Note to reader: My math is very wrong, if you come across this when searching please read the comments!
I have a process
\begin{equation}
\tag{1}
dX_t = \mu(X_t, t)dt + \sigma X_t dW_t,
\end{equation}
with $\mu(X_t, t)$ an arbitrary (smooth) function, and $\sigma$ a known constant.
I aim to obtain $\mathbb{E}(X_t)$ and $\mathbb{V}(X_t)$.
$\mathbb{E}(X_t)$ is easily obtained by $$\tag{2}\mathbb{E}(X_t) = X_0 + \int_0^t \mu(X_s, s) \ ds,$$ which can be efficiently estimated using an ODE solver.
However, I am stuck on trying to obtain the variance $\mathbb{V}(X_t)$.
I have attempted to use the identity $\mathbb{V}(X_t) = \mathbb{E}((X_t - \mathbb{E}(X_t))^2)$, wherein
$$\tag{3}d(X_t - \mathbb{E}(X_t)) = (\mu(X_t, t)dt + \sigma X_t dW_t) - (\mu(X_t, t)dt) = \sigma X_t dW_t,$$
from which I apply Ito's lemma with $Y_t = (X_t - \mathbb{E}(X_t))^2$ to obtain
$$\tag{4}dY = \sigma^2 X_t^2 dt + 2 \sigma X_t^2 dW_t,$$ from which the expectation is
$$\tag{5}\mathbb{E}(Y_t) = \mathbb{E((X_t - \mathbb{E}(X_t))^2)} = \mathbb{V}(X_t)= \int_0^t \sigma^2 X_s^2 \ ds.$$
I attepted to validate this using simulations, and whilst the term I derived for expectation aligns with the simulation results, the term I derived for variances does not (and is in fact off by orders of magnitude).
I therefore believe that I have made a mistake in my derivation, but I am not experienced enough with stochastic calculus to find it, and keep ending up doing the same derivation over and over again. I have the feeling that I am missing something obvious; any help would be much appreciated.
Experimemtally the distribution of $X_t$ seems to be lognormal for the types of $\mu$s I am interested in, so perhaps it would be prudent to formulate the problem in terms of $\log(X_t)$ so that the distribution parameters of $X_t$ are easy to obtain? Although knowing my luck the distribution is not lognormal and my eyes are tricking me after staring at this problem for too long.
Edit: In general $\mu(X_t, t)$ is the output of a neural network so eludes easy analysis.
I believe (although I may be wrong) that we can obtain $\mathbb{E}(X_t)$ by solving the differential equation
$$\tag{6}\frac{dX}{dt} = \mu(X, t) \ dt,$$
with $X_0$ known. We can solve this using an ODE solver.
Apparently this may be wrong, although I do not necessarily understand where.
The expectation of the diffusion term is $0$ I think, and the solution I obtain aligns extremely closely with simulation results.
(Note, the above formula is wrong, if you came across this in your searching DO NOT USE IT!)

The above plot shows my formulation for the expectation (which is wrong I now think) in blue, and the mean of an ensemble of 50000 simulations in red. We see they are close, but not in perfect agreement. Note that for the above plot we have
$$\tag{7} dX_t = \left(0.005X_t + (6 - X_t) \exp(-t/30)\right) \ dt + 0.2X_t \ dW_t,$$
and hence set $\mu(X_t, t) = 0.005X_t + (6 - X_t) \exp(-t/30)$ and $\sigma = 0.2$. I stress that these are arbitrary choices, but I needed something to simulate in order to check my work. The real $\mu(X_t, t)$ is given by a neural network, and therefore is not affine in $X_t$ so cannot be solved by separation and bringing in the expectation.

I don't think your formula for $\mathbb{E}(X_t)$ is correct.

Adding to NN2's comment. Hint: is $\mu(X_s,s)$ deterministic or stochastic? What is the correct term after we took the expectation? Besides: I don't think there is a simple answer to your original question because $\mu(X_s,s)$ does not allow to  pull in $\mathbb E,.$

@NN2 Checking experimentally, the expectation I gave seems to be correct for the $\mu$ that I have. Maybe I am missing something but it seems to work in my case.

@Kurt I am unsure what you mean, $\mu(X_t, t)$ is a function of $X_t$ and $t$, as $X_t$ is stochastic the output of the function is stochastic, but $\mu(X_t, t)$ itselt is fixed given $X_t$ and $t$. For example $\mu(X_t, t) = \exp(-t) (6-X_t) + 0.05 X_t$ is one potential formulation. In practice $\mu(X_t, t)$ is given by a neural network, so kind of eludes easy analysis and breaking down.

In general you should number your equations to make the discussion easier. Correct: $\mu(X_t,t)$ is stochastic. Can we then have $$\mathbb{E}(X_t) = X_0 + \int_0^t \mu(X_s, s) \ ds,?$$ Hint: the left hand side of this is not stochastic.

@Kurt Thank you for the comment, I have updated the post. It would seem not, as I would think that the integral of a stochastic function is itself stochastic? (Again, this is new to me, I tend to work in discrete time).
It is odd though that it aligns with the simulation results so closely! Perhaps I am writing what I am doing wrong, but I just solve Eq (6) and the result is very close to the mean of the simulation. Although in retrospect it does seem to constantly be biased.

Ah, perhaps the answer is
$$\mathbb{E}(X_t) = X_0 + \mathbb{E}\left(\int_0^t\mu(X_s, s) \ ds\right).$$ In that case I am not sure that we can do anything, as $\mu(X_t, t)$ is an arbitrary function of $X_t$ and $t$.

For a general $\mu$ your problem is not solvable other than simulating $X_t$ by using its SDE. Then you can calculate whatever you want $\mathbb EX_t,\mathbb VE_t$ and so on.

@Kurt Ah, so in general there is no closed form solution for this! I had a feeling this was the case, but it seems like a simple extension to the GBM, so I thought it worth a shot.
To conclude, my new understanding is that there is no solution to either the expectation $\mathbb{E}(X_t)$ or the variance $\mathbb{V}(X_t)$ in terms of deterministic integrals, and therefore the problem can only be solved using SDE simulation techniques. Do you believe this to be the case?

Not quite. Your $\mu(X_t,t)$ in (7) is affine linear in $X_t,.$ You can pull in $\mathbb E$ into it. This also kills the Brownian term and there you have the ODE for $\mathbb EX_t,.$

@Kurt Yes in that example it is affine and linear in X_t, however in general it is not. As mentioned, the actual use case is a neural network outputting $\mu(X_t, t)$, with the diffusion term adding some uncertainty quantification. Now that I have had my coffee I see that I dropped an expectation. The affine linear case is relatively simple to solve but that is not the actual use case unfortunately.

Besides what Kurt.G said (you need to add an expectation over the integral of the drift), the expectation $\mathbb{E}(X_t)$ is correct only if $\mathbb{E} \left( \int X_s dW_s \right) = 0$ (which does not hold in general case, unless $X_t$ is deterministic)

The best formula relating to the expectation you may have is
$$\mathbb{E}(\ln(X_t)) - \ln(X_0) = \mathbb{E} \left(\int_0^t \left(\frac{\mu(X_s,s)}{X_s} - \frac{\sigma^2}{2}ds \right)\right)$$
You can get this formula by applying the Ito's formula to $\ln(X_t)$ and take the expectation.

@NN2 Yes it seems as though I need to go over stochastic calculus again when I get the time. I am led to believe that the question I have asked (that is, find some expression for $\mathbb{E}(X_t)$ and $\mathbb{V}(X_t)$ in terms of deterministic functions) has no answer. I thought that integrals wrt brownian motion have expectation 0, clearly that is not the case. Again, I need to go over stochastic calculus, it has been around 10 years since I was taught it! Thanks for bringing this additional error to light!

I have a feeling that the formula @NN2 just posted, whilst useful, is not particularly helpful for arbitrary $\mu(X_t, t)$, as we do not have the cancellation we do in the try GBM, so we still have a stochastic integral which would require simulation. I may be wrong though!

First of all, thanks for adding the disclaimers to the body of the question :). Finally: we can close the matter now since you understood the problems and are versed in doing the simulations. You can therefore test every heuristic that someone suggests.
